# A simple clojure implementation of data base

Tags: database, clojure

I'm learning Clojure and I'm looking for some existing project (github,etc.) that implements a simple data base principles (CRUD) to learn from.

There is no need of users access, and even saved files, just the basics of implementation of lists\maps as tables and parsing queries for it.

thanks.

EDIT:

This is the final work:  [QuickDB](https://github.com/guypld/QuickDB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FleetDB](http://fleetdb.org/) is a simple database implemented in Clojure.